# Client time settings broke readable date in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, time, timezone

What i'm trying to do is show date in more readable format like 3 seconds ago, 1 hours ago, yesterday, June 12 and etc.
What i did is , first calculate the timestamp for comment's date.. Then send it to client with ajax, then create two date instance on javascript one for is comment's date and other one is current date.. After that I just find differences between to date item then write on the screen with fancy words.. 
Everything works fine on localhost, even server.. But sometimes if client's pc date is earlier from the server date (independent from time zone)..
Let say server time is today 13.30 pm and client time is today 13.00 , it's failing with this scenario because current time is being comment's post time.. Difference will be negative value..
I'm creating date object for comment in php like this;

```
date("Y-m-d G:i:s")
```

Then write it to mysql db..
After that when i select comments i convert it to timestamp to push it on client side with ;

```
$comment['timestamp'] = strtotime($row['creationDate']);
```

And then in javascript, I make calculation for human readable date format ;

```
DateObject.getFormatted = function(unixtime){

d = new Date(unixtime*1000);
now = new Date();

var diff = (now.getTime()/1000- unixtime) ;
var result = "";

var MIN = 60,
    HOUR = 3600,
    DAY = 86400;

if(diff < 2)
    result ="just now";
else if(diff < MIN)
    result = Math.floor(diff) + " seconds ago";
else if(diff < HOUR)
    result = Math.floor(diff/60) + " minutes ago"; 
else if(diff < DAY)
    result = Math.floor(diff/3600) + " hours ago";
else if(diff < DAY*3)
{   
    var days = diff/DAY;
    if(days < 2)
        result = "yesterday";
    else
        result = Math.floor(days) + " days ago"; 
}
else if(now.getFullYear() == d.getFullYear())
{
    formattedTime = this.getTime(d);
    result = this.getSameYear(d) + " at " + formattedTime;
}
else
{
    formattedDate = this.getDate(d); 
    formattedTime = this.getTime(d);
    result = formattedDate + " at " + formattedTime;
}       

return result;




};
```

So if clients date is earlier then the comment's date diff value is being negative, so the first case would be true

```
if(diff < 2)
result ="just now";
```

It's going behing as time difference between client and comment's date .. In my case 10 minutes.. If I set my computer time 10 minutes later it's working nice..
So how can i fix it in a better way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be better send from server to client difference between comment date and current date?(instead of creation two javascript date instances)

Comment: yeah it's a option but i dont want to do it. Because I'm plannig to change date dynamically on client side without refreshing pages just like facebook

Comment: Actually, you should work only with difference between comment-date and current date.

I think about such algorithm:
1. Get difference from server, place it at client-side as javascript-object and show in human readable format (e.g. 1 hour ago).
2. Increase this local javascript object value (with help of javascript function `setInterval`) and show this updated value to user.

Answer (score 0):

A third date so you can calculate the difference between server and client and use it as an offset?

Comment: it's all working on cient, how can i calculate difference as offset? should i send current time from php also?

Comment: Aye request server time when you get the data.